# Deleting backups with `find -mtime +n` – more backups remain than expected

Tags: linux, backup, find

This is my script:

```
find /backup/dir -mindepth 1 -depth -mtime +4 -exec rm -rf \{\} \;
```

And after this I have always not last 4 backups but 5.

I think find sucks for this. Maybe someone have any idea how to use other tool in this?

Comment: Are the backups in separate directories under `/backup/dir/`? While using `rm -r` anyway, `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` may be a more elegant approach (no need for `-depth` then).

Answer (score 1):

> I think find sucks for this. Maybe someone have any idea how to use other tool in this?

`find` may still be the right tool.

From [`man find`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/debian/1/find/):

> `-mtime n`
> File's data was last modified `n*24` hours ago. See the comments for `-atime` to understand how rounding affects the interpretation of file modification times.
>
> […]
>
> Numeric arguments can be specified as
>
> `+n` for greater than `n`,
> […]

The relevant comment is

> When `find` figures out how many 24-hour periods ago the file was last accessed, any fractional part is ignored, so to match `-atime +1`, a file has to have been accessed at least two days ago.

This means `0` is possible. With `-mtime +4` backups that report `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` or `4` are left intact. I assume your backups are daily so each of the mentioned numbers is reported exactly once. Five numbers, five backups don't pass the test, five backups remain.

If you use `-mtime +3` instead of `-mtime +4` then backups that report `0`, `1`, `2` or `3` will remain; probably four backups total, the number you wanted.

See also [*Why does the behaviour of `find` differ using `-mtime -0` vs. `+0`?*](https://superuser.com/q/1214566/432690)